# Adding a legacy address to an existing Electrum wallet

Tags: address, electrum, mnemonic-seed, ledger-hardware-wallet

Using ledger nano s I created several addresses - native segwit, taproot, legacy, etc.

I sent to one of them a small amount and it shows up.

I later re-created the wallet using the BIP39 phrase in Electrum. However, I see only one of the addresses (native segwit).Is there a chance that I can add the legacy address to the Electrum wallet, too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can add it to your `electrum` wallet as well, it support importing different types of addresses, you just gonna have to create a separate wallets for each address type (legacy, SegWit, and native SegWit) because each of them use different derivation paths.